# Springboot Event Logging

Tags: spring-boot, logging, message-queue, aop

I have a scheduled task in a fixed rate, that reads a queue.
Each message that comes from the queue has an ID.

I wanna know if it's possible split the log by ID, appending to a different file.

I was thinking about use aspects or a custom appender, one of these can do the job for me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after some search I've remembered of MDC (Mapped Diagnostic Context) wich can do what I want with almost no workarounds.

I just need to add a SiftingAppender to the logback-spring.xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration debug="false">
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/>
    <appender name="SIFT" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.sift.SiftingAppender">
        <discriminator>
            <key>checkoutId</key>
            <defaultValue>system</defaultValue>
        </discriminator>
        <sift>
            <appender name="${checkoutId}" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
                <file>${checkoutId}.log</file>
                <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
                    <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss:SSS} | %-5level | %thread | %logger{20} | %msg%n%rEx</pattern>
                </layout>
            </appender>
        </sift>
    </appender>
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="SIFT" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Than I call like that:

```
@Scheduled(initialDelayString = "${consumeStart:10000}", fixedRateString = "${consumeRate:5000}")
private void task() {
    try {
        val message = queue.get(timeout);
        if (message != null) {
            MDC.put("checkoutId", message.toString());
            . . .
        }
    } finally {
        MDC.remove("checkoutId");
    }
}
```